# Manage stale web socket session in JavaEE

Tags: jakarta-ee, websocket

I am working on a JavaEE web socket project for establishing web socket connection with the android mobile. 
In my project I need to remember web socket session of connected client in my server side.

If the mobile client manually disconnect than his session will get removed from my session map so there is not problem but if the web socket connection gets cancelled but turning out wifi than server does not receive socket close request and hence there will be stale web socket session in my session map.
My Question is how to know if the session in my session map is active or not in these scenario.

What I have tried is that I try to ping client using session object from my session map but it always sends me pong message either or not the client is active or not. Help mee with good suggestions.

Comment: If your mobile app needs to be connected then you listen to HttpSessionListener. in 30 minutes (the timeout of the httpsession) if no activity occurs from your client the httpsession gets destroyed. At that time  you can remove your websocket from your cache. hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on session destroy.

Assuming that you've a CDI [`@SessionScoped`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/context/SessionScoped.html) managed bean, use [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html).

```
@SessionScoped
public class SocketManager implements Serializable {

    // ...

    @PreDestroy
    public void sessionDestroyed() {
        // Close web sockets here.
    }

}
```

Or, if you don't have CDI at hands, use [`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html#sessionDestroyed-javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent-).

```
@WebListener
public class SocketManager implements HttpSessionListener {

    // ...

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // Close web sockets here.
    }

}
```

That said, storing unserializable web socket sessions in the HTTP session is a bad idea. Rather store them in the application scope, keyed by some unique identifier which you in turn associate with HTTP session.

Comment: Does Http session get created when web socket connection is made by the client????

Comment: Nope, it's not created when WS session starts. It's only created when HTTP session starts. Normally, by just opening a JSP/Facelets page for the first time during a client session.